# How to detect chrome extensions whether it is installed in user browser

Tags: javascript

There are a lot of answers related to this question, but most of those answer information are deprecated years ago by chrome browser.

I need a working example, how to detect google chrome browser addon/extension which is installed in users browser using (javascript/any method).

> If i use event detection, there is a addon called " **Luminous:
>   JavaScript events blocker**" which blocks all event detection and bypass
>   the events generated by javascript.

Comment: Do you want to detect your own extension or are you talking about detecting a 3rd-party extension?

Comment: Its about 3rd-party extension, which is used by hackers who access my website to spam. So, im looking for a way to detect those public existing extension and block them from entering into the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <script>
(function(w, u){
  var intervalLuminous = null;
  var isLuminousInstalled = false;
  var setLuminousDetected = function(){
    isLuminousInstalled = true;
    alert('Luminous: JavaScript events blocker installed!');
  }
  var checkLuminous = function(){
    if (document.getElementById('luminous-options') || document.getElementById('luminous-data')) {
      clearInterval(intervalLuminous);
      setLuminousDetected();
    }
  }

  intervalLuminous = setInterval(function(){
    checkLuminous();
  }, 10);
  if(!intervalLuminous){
    setLuminousDetected();
  }

})(window, undefined);
</script>
```